# HTML5 Canvas: get curve's coordinates

Tags: coordinates, html5-canvas, kineticjs, curve

I have a quadratic curve in canvas (defined by start, end and control point). What I need is to get more of the curve's coordinates (eg. the middle, quarters etc.). With that, I'd be able (after a few iterations of finding coordinates) to animate an object based on this curve (I know it can be done easily with SVG, but that's not an option).

[image]

*image taken from http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-quadratic-curves/*

Is there an easy way to do this? When I checked for bisecting curve on google, the only thing I found was some complicated Math including drawing, which is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These functions may be of interest to you:

```
Kinetic.Path.getPointOnCubicBezier = function(pct, P1x, P1y, P2x, P2y, P3x, P3y, P4x, P4y)
Kinetic.Path.getPointOnQuadraticBezier = function(pct, P1x, P1y, P2x, P2y, P3x, P3y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am seeking a similar solution for bezier curves. How do I get a list of the coordinates on the curve?

To solve your problem, perhaps you could plugin the x-coordinate (or y-coordinate) into the quadratic equation:

y = a*x^2 + b*x + c

I can't seem to find a function that returns the coordinates of the curve. It would be nice to get a list of the coordinates for any curve / shape.

Comment: but you don't really know `a` and `b` when constructing the curve via canvas, do you?